# Is it possible to get the embedding table in tf_hub models?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

I'm having problems with finetuning a BERT model. I was previously using `get_transformer_encoder()` in `official.nlp` and `MLM` task in `official.nlp` to train a BERT. But this seems like tough, so I changed to finetuning a pretrained BERT model. But to also complete the `MLM` task, it seems like I need to get the embedding table from the `tf_hub` models. I think it's possible to extract the embedding table from the hub models, but I don't know whether there are some functions I can use to get them more quickly, Thanks.

Comment: If you are finetuning with your own task, most of time you don't need to worry about the MLM task any more. Using the loss at your own task should be sufficient. With that said, `tf_hub` with trainable BERT parameters should be enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might could help finetune a pretrained model using `tensorflow_hub` with MLM task, we can use `keras_nlp` from `official.nlp`.

Here is a simple example:

```
bert_encoder_scratch = get_transformer_encoder(config)
bert_encoder_pretrain = hub.KerasLayer(hub.load(module_url), trainable=True)
```

if you are training from scratch:

```
mlm_model = keras_nlp.layers.MaskedLM(embedding_table=bert_encoder_scratch.get_embedding_table())
```

So in this way, what lacks for a hub model is to find the embedding table. Find the variable `word_embedding` by:

```
bert_encoder_pretrain.trainable_variables
```

or you can use `tf.get_variable()`. Here I simply write `bert_encoder_pretrain.trainable_variables[0]`

The mlm task would be:

```
mlm_model = keras_nlp.layers.MaskedLM(embedding_table=bert_encoder_pretrain.trainable_variables[0])
```

Then you get your `seq_output` from the model, and also `masked_positions`, here I define it as:

```
masked_positions = tf.broadcast_to(tf.range(0, seq_length), [batch_size, seq_length])
```

You will get the `mlm_logits` from the model by:

```
mlm_logits = mlm_model(seq_output, masked_positions)
```

I have tested this approach in my model.